# Regex for redirect in .net core rewrite module infinite loop

Tags: regex, reactjs, url-rewriting, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to incorporate the URL rewriting middleware in my `.Net Core` app and for some reason when trying to define the redirect regex rules, it goes into an infinite loop.

I'm using `.NET Core 1.1` and a `React.JS` app with react-router (client-side) routing. Essentially I want any explicit url entered or refreshed outside of root to just redirect to root. The rule that is giving me an infinite loop is this:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirect("(.*)", "/")
);
```

From what I understand, the rewriter already takes into account the base domain so I don't have to worry about checking for something like `(^http://localhost:8080)`. I'm fairly certain the simple regex I have above should work.

Any help appreciated. The [url rewriting package is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting) for those not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regex is that it matches even root url:

```
var str = "/";
Console.WriteLine($"Output: {Regex.Match(str, "(.*)")}");

>>> Output: /
```

So you need to exclude your root from it, by replacing `*` with `+`, so there must be at least one character after `/`:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirect("(.+)", "/")
);
```